# Check if a word exists in a subset of a node

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a function that takes a word, a board, and two board indices: a row index and a column index and return true iff the word exists on the board starting at row ri, column ci and tracing a path that only moves either left or up from the position ri, ci (just like x,y on a graph).

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 . . . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . . .
2 . . . . . . . . .
3 . . . . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . . .
5 . . . . . . . . .
6 . . . . . . . . .

#|
   A Board is one of:
   – empty
   – (cons [ListOf X] Board) -board-cols items long 

   [ListOf X] is board-rows items long

   board? : X -> Bool
   make-board :  Nat Nat X -> Board
|# 
(define-struct board [rows cols content])
```

This should be in ISL+ with only one helper if needed, but no other locals, helpers, lambdas, lets, etc. and should be a binary tree recursion.

I believe I'm pretty close to solving this, but I keep having only some of the check-expects pass. Here's what I've done:

```
 ;returns a character at the location
 ;this function doesn't count as a helper
    (define (board-ref b row col)
      (if (or (< (board-rows b) row) (< (board-cols b) col)) false
          (string-ref (list-ref (board-content b) row) col)))    

    ; find? : String Board Row Col -> Bool
        (define (find? w b ri ci)
          (local [(define (help w b ri ci n)
                    (cond 
                      [(= n (sub1 (string-length w))) true]
                      [else 
           (and (equal? (string-ref w n) (board-ref b ri ci))
                (or (equal? (string-ref w n) (help w b (sub1 ri) ci (add1 n)))  
                    (equal? (string-ref w n) (help w b ri (sub1 ci) (add1 n)))))]))] 
        (help w b ri ci 0)))
```

Checks:

```
(define b0 (make-board 1 1 (list "x")))
(define b1 (make-board 5 5 
                       (list "reuta" "trmfk" "holte" "nsicd" "cexly")))
(define b2 (make-board 3 7 (list "jkialmw" "ienloer" "syilzbt")))
#;(check-expect (find? "x" b0 0 0) true)
#;(check-expect (find? "sort" b1 3 1) true)
#;(check-expect (find? "aikj" b2 0 3) true)
#;(check-expect (find? "aikji" b2 0 3) false)
```

Any help would go a long way.

Comment: You need to explain " and tracing a path that only moves either left or up."

Comment: Added to the explanation. Left would be sub1 ri and up would be sub1 ci until you get to 0,0 on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got three issues it looks like:

```
 [(= n (sub1 (string-length w))) true]
```

What happens if you try to run `(find? "q" b0 0 0)`? That should obviously fail, but it doesn't. You're declaring a match one character too soon. (Which means single character strings can be found everywhere.) Just think about the one character case; `(string-length "q")` is 0. You start your recursion off by invoking `help` with `n` as 0.

```
 (or (equal? (string-ref w n) (board-ref b ri ci))
     (help w b (sub1 ri) ci (add1 n))    
     (help w b ri (sub1 ci) (add1 n)))]))]
```

Think about how you'd explain that code to someone. It'd go something like "Return true, if the current character matches, or the recursive call up suceeds, or the recursive call to the left succeeds."

You need the current character (`(string-ref w n)`) to match on every call. `or` comes into play with the two recursive calls; you don't care which one of them succeeds, you just need one of them to.

```
  (if (or (< (board-rows b) row)
          (< (board-cols b) col))
      false
      (string-ref (list-ref (board-content b) row) col)))
```

What happens when you hit the top or left edge, and you've still got letters left that you're looking for? `row` and `col` will go negative, and then `list-ref` and `string-ref` won't be happy. In your comment to soegaard, you say the recursion should go up until you get to 0,0. But what actually stops you there?

Comment: Fixed the else statement, but still unsure about the base case.

Comment: I elaborated a bit further on the remaining issues.